# Howto override GetString() method of ResourceManager (in c# asp mvc) depending on some internal flags

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, localization

I have this project written in asp.net mvc with Razor views, which is available in 4 languages.

To understand a bit my need... let's say that the website is something dedicated to DOGS. So all localization strings in the project relate to DOGS at this moment. Now I want to extend it to also support CATS / SQUIRRELS etc. In the project, i use something like Resources.AllDogs which translates to "All dogs" (english, and other langs). In some other areas, it's a text like Resources.IsYourDogDoingWellToday "Is your dog doing well today?"

Now, what I though of doing is have a "patcher" function, that replaces "dogs" with "cats", "dog" with "cat", "Dog" with "Cat" etc... in all languages, whenever needed in the UI, based on some internal configuration of the project.

Found how to accomplish this using a rewrite of WebViewPage ([Changing ResourceManager (Make it Updatable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787244/changing-resourcemanager-make-it-updatable)) but this requires me to replace hundreds of lines in so many source files to adapt them to such a new change (replace all Resources.############ with a GetString("", someConfigParam)

Then found some guides here about making your project load a different resx file if needed. This is also a viable solution, but requires me to maintain not 4 but 4 + (4 for cats) + (4 for squirrels) files... too much to maintain, not something I'd choose

Found also a topic about how to rewrite the ResourceManager (some changes in startup.cs, and ofc the override of GetString methods) but wasn't able to make it work

How would you guys accomplish this?

Comment: You can try "patching" your strings but this will be, by nature, unpredictable. I guess it depends on your level of tolerance for silly, unintended strings. If you want to support multiple languages and multiple targets (e.g. dogs, cats) properly, you'll need to maintain a set of resources for each combination but you may get around the trouble using placeholders for the objects. Impossible to tell without knowing the actual problem domain.

Comment: What I did for the moment is created a helper method that i call on interest-strings in order to "patch" at runtime the translation. Seems to work, was not much work to make the change and will be easy to maintain in the future.